# Firing an event from Phaser game JS to outer JS?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm creating a Phaser game that will form part of a larger JS application. When a player completes a level I need the game to be hidden to move back to performing other tasks before the game shows again at a later stage on the next level.

I'm having a hard time finding a sensible way to fire an event (or another way to call a callback function) from a `Phaser.Game` to the JS that instantiated it.

The only think I've thought of at the moment is to manually add the callback to the game:

```
function onLevelComplete() {
  // example callback function
}

this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, this.el);
this.game.levelCompleteCallback = onLevelComplete;
```

Then anywhere were the `Phaser.Game` is available (e.g. within a state) I could do `this.game.levelCompleteCallback()`.

The trouble is that this feels really tightly coupled. What I want is a way to do something like `this.game.fireEvent('levelComplete')` and not have to care whether there's anything listening at the other side.

Is there anything built in that I'm missing that would allow me to do what I need?

Comment: I don't see how `this.game.fireEvent('levelComplete')` is any less coupled than `this.game.levelCompleteCallback()`. You would still have to provide a way to *listen* to the events being fired.

Comment: Because if `this.game.levelCompleteCallback` isn't set then you'd get an error. Therefore the code would need to check for it being a function and so on. Event systems exist for exactly this situation - 0 or more functions attached when something happens.

Comment: you can just do `if (this.game.levelCompleteCallback != undefined)` or something similar. Wrap that in a `callGameLevelComplete()` if necessary.

Comment: Probably better to do a `typeof` but yeah, you're right. However, what if two things need to listen for that? The callback route then becomes messy. It's synonymous with `el.onClick = function() { ... }` vs `el.addEventListener`. Phaser has the `Signal` event system so why not use it as per the accepted answer?

Comment: I agree callbacks become messy. I suppose non-event-based callbacks can be called more coupled because you have to have multiple callback properties for everything that wants to hook (though it's not dynamic in the amount of listeners). I'm unfamiliar with the Phaser API: if `Signal` works for this purpose, then that's great :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a Signal from within your game:

```
this.onLevelComplete = new Phaser.Signal();

...

// some condition is met
this.onLevelComplete.dispatch();
```

As long as the Signal is exposed to the app above it can register itself with it quite easily. Perhaps a single global object (gameEvents?), or a route to the current State, or perhaps the game passes a reference to the events into the app somewhere. There are myriad ways of doing this.

```
function appDoesSomething() {}

gameEvents.onLevelComplete.add(this.appDoesSomething, this);
```

Either way, the end result is that the game can fire off the signals happily without caring if the app is listening or not.

It's impossible to have this set-up fully decoupled though, they are joined somewhere. It's just up to you where.

Comment: I already had a namespace for all my game components. (e.g. `Game.States.Play`) so I added `Game.events` and `Game.events.onLevelComplete` as the `Signal`. Anything else can then listen with `Game.events.onLevelComplete.add` as you suggested. Thanks for the guidance!